# USB ports not working after resume from sleep on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, 18.04

Recently i installed Ubuntu 18.04 and started to face a strange issue. 
while i went to sleep/hibernate mode two of my three USB ports stopped working.

If i restart Ubuntu the USB ports goes back to normal mode.

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb` before and after the sleep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer from [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342953/322816) (slightly enhanced here) has a solution.

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and find the line containing `LINUX_DEFAULT`. Change the line from:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
   ```
2. Save the file, run `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.
3. After using this, you will find:

   ```
   $ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
   -1
   ```

   The default value is `2`. The kernel parameter changes this value.

Setting the kernel parameter helped me. Now my mouse works again when resuming from suspend.

Suggestion: When USB devices don't work after suspend, you can also reload the driver using the following commands as root:

```
modprobe -r uhci_hcd
modprobe uhci_hcd
```

and/or:

```
modprobe -r ehci_hcd
modprobe ehci_hcd
```

Comment: This seems to have worked on 18.04.2.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer did not work for me and I also don't want to keep up with kernel parameters whenever I reinstall or update grub or boot from another os or whatever. There is a file called `usbreset` that installs along with `usbutils`. Run that, find the name of the device you want to restart upon wake and put a file into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` I call mine reset-mouse so my file is `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset-mouse`.

If you have that folder, just look at another entry for the format. Mine is:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    usbreset "Wireless Device"
    ;;
esac
```

I got the name "Wireless Device" by running `usbreset` from terminal which will also list your devices and tell their name, so whatever device you have a problem with.

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset-mouse
```

Then next time my machine went to sleep, and every time after that, it wakes up immediately with no USB issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and [found a solution](https://itsfoss.community/t/usb-2-0-ports-doesn-t-works-after-suspend-mode/2850/28) similar to the answer by @Rasheed.

First, find the devices IDs with `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b539 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2a7a:9a18 CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In my case, devices 002 and 004. Then create a file inside `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and make it executable.
Mine has this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    post)
    echo  "2a7a:9a18" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci/unbind
    echo  "2a7a:9a18" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci/bind
    echo  "1ea7:0064" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci/unbind
    echo  "1ea7:0064" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci/bind
    ;;
esac
```

Now, mouse and keyboard work again after waking.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on a Dell Precision

Answer (score 1):

I've recently came across the same problem.
What my solution is with

`echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/reset`

`echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/remove`

`echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/rescan`

You can go into `/sys/bus/pci/devices` to get the list of the devices

use `lspci -s` to get which code for which device

for my example, my code ` lspci -s 05:00.0 ' give me the result
"  USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller"

So I know this is the usb device I need to reset, after reset, I can reconnect my usb device without rebooting.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! I've tried everything without success. The command "echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/rescan" worked.