# Sometimes, after reboot or suspend, docking station isn't fully working

Tags: suspend, 21.04, docking

I have a Dell Precision 5750, CalDigit TS3+, and Ubuntu 21.04.  I have a widescreen Samsung monitor plugged into the Caldigit via DisplayPort. This combination works fine on various other OS's using the same hardware (Garuda, Arch, Windows).  On Ubuntu 21.04, sometimes, when the laptop goes to sleep, or I restart it, parts of the CalDigit seem to no longer be working.  The monitor still works, but the Caldigits Ethernet, audio, and USB ports no longer seem to be functioning.  Unplugging the CalDigit and plugging it back in seems to fix everything, until the next time. The laptop has 4 USB Type C 3.2 TB3 ports.  I've tried 2 of them, and seen similar behavior. I reset the BIOS to factory defaults.  I've reviewed a few of the similar questions suggested here, but didn't want to make changes from a question that never got an answer, or didn't really seem similar to my problem.

- [1308659](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308659/caldigit-thunderbolt-3-dock-usb-ports) Similar problem, no solution.
- [1168018](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168018/portable-monitor-isnt-detected-after-sleep) USB problem, not really related as all my ports are TB3.

Seeings how it happens on a restart too, I don't think its a suspend problem, but I'm not sure.  Where/How should I start troubleshooting this at?

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem..
Try this.. Will work better..

edit file (with sudo):
/etc/systemd/logind.conf

change these lines to:

> HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
> HoldoffTimeoutSec=120s

You can even try more than 120s but this works fine with my system.
When for some reason dock goes to "sleep" (meaning screen goes blank) just touch "ESC" twice.

Good luck and Let me know.

Comment: Will give it a try.  `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower` Will this disable suspending when I shut the lid and its not plugged in?  Was reading [the docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man5/logind.conf.5.html).

Comment: Nop. it will disable lid switch when connected to power. I have a notebook on a vertical stand closed and connected to a dock with two screens, keyb, etc. So, at home, works as a desktop. I came to that solution after reading the docs too.

Comment: OK, problem still persisted.  After EVERY reboot.  I disabled all my extensions, themes, tweaks, etc...  I made a new user and it happened there as well.  That got me thinking it was something outside of the OS now.  I went and checked my bios, turned on `Enable Thunderbolt Boot Support` and that seems to have fixed it!  Thanks for your help @jpbrain !

Answer (score 1):

The factory reset on the bios turned off `Enable Thunderbolt Boot Support`.  Turning that back on has resolved the problem.  Special thanks to @jpbrain for getting me unstuck.