# (kernel?) bug: USB and webcam no more detected after wake up from sleep

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, suspend

I have a quite uncommon problem on ubuntu 20.04 since I installed it on a new computer.
My usb ports and webcam are perfectly working just after boot. But after wakup from sleep (some times 2 suspends are necessary) both of them are no more detected. (I guess the issue is only with USB but that the webcam is internally connected with USB)

- webcam no more in `/dev/video*`
- no any USB connected devices in `lsusb`

I tried to find more detail about this in `dmesg` but found nothing related (I'm not an expert so doesn't mean there is nothing at all).

Do someone know a solution, or how I can investigate on this ?

### note

maybe the suspend is not the relevant (or not the only ) factor because this already happend once while I was using the computer: suddenly the mouse disconnected and when I checked all other devices were gone.

### config

- Asus Zenbook flip 14 UM462DA
- AMD ryzen 5 3500U
- ubuntu 20.04 (up to date on 2020.11.05)
- distro kernel (linux 5.4.0-52-generic)

Comment: oops sorry, I will report it on launchpad
But this was if someone had a trick to avoid the issue, for instance restarting the proper module.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. If somebody finds a workaround that allows me to start my webcam, say from the command line interface, without having to reboot my laptop, I love him or her very very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB ports not working after resume from sleep on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044988/usb-ports-not-working-after-resume-from-sleep-on-ubuntu-18-04)