# mouse quits working after suspend

Tags: 20.04, usb, mouse, laptop

I have a usb mouse and its quits working after my laptop wakes from suspend. I have to pull it out and re-plug it back in to get it to work again. Can someone help me fix this issue?
I am running ubuntu mate 20.04.3

Comment: [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1331450/1222991) might give you what you need 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB ports not working after resume from sleep on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044988/usb-ports-not-working-after-resume-from-sleep-on-ubuntu-18-04)